# How to develop cascading dropdowns in spring 4 using thymeleaf

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf, dropdown

i have a difficulty in developing cascading dropdowns in spring 4 with thymeleaf.

Here is my scenario:

i have 2 dropdowns like state and city. based on state selection, i need to populate city dropdown with corresponding cities for that state.

I am using Spring boot, spring 4 and thymeleaf template for view.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to **Dropdown / List selectors** ?

Could I help you now. Please read this article.

Select fields have two parts: the `<select>` tag and its nested `<option>` tags. When creating this kind of field, only the `<select>` tag has to include a `th:field` attribute, but the `th:value` attributes in the nested `<option>` tags will be very important because they will provide the means of knowing which is the currently selected option (in a similar way to non-boolean checkboxes and radio buttons).

#### *Let’s re-build the type field as a dropdown select:*

```
<select th:field="*{type}">
  <option th:each="type : ${allTypes}" 
          th:value="${type}" 
          th:text="#{${'seedstarter.type.' + type}}">Wireframe</option>
</select>
```

also you can check this  [Thymeleaf Website](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/thymeleafspring.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [appelsiini chained select](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/chained) to implement the cascading dropdown.

**template.html**

```
<select th:field="*{state}">
    <option value="0">--</option>
    <option th:each="state : ${states}" th:value="${state.stateId}" th:text="${state.name}">Florida</option>
</select>
<select th:field="*{city}">
    <option value="0">--</option>
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#city").remoteChained({
        parents: "#state",
        url: /*[[@{/getStateCityValues}]]*/ ""
    });
</script>
```

**Controller.java**

```
@PostMapping("/getStateCityValues")
public @ResponseBody
Map<String, String> getStateCityValues(@RequestParam("state") Integer state) {
    Map<String, String> cityValues = new HashMap<>();

    List<City> cities = cityService.getStateCities(state);

    for(City city : cities){
        cityValues.put(String.valueOf(city.getCityId()), city.getName());
    }

    return cityValues;  
}
```